# How to insert ASCII control characters into a TCL string?

Tags: tcl

I need to create a TCL script that contains ASCII control characters. This is the full list of these characters from the ASCII table but I am only interested in putting in the "start of text" value 2 and "end of text" value 3.

[image]

Comment: Please do not post unnecessary images. People who are able to help you know where to find the ASCII table.

Comment: I was telling about what part of the table I am referring to. The strange this is, when I set a variable to 0, and convert it to ASCII, I get the ASCII value for the character 0. It seemed to be an impossible task to get what I wanted so I posted it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enter a hex code in a string by writing `\xnn` where `nn` is the code, e.g.

```
set start_of_text "\x02"
set end_of_text "\x03"
```

See the documentation at https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M27

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `format` with the `%c` code (which might be more useful if you don't know the relevant number until run-time because it's in a variable or whatever):

```
set ascii(STX) [format %c 2]
set ascii(ETX) [format %c 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm going to be wrapping text in a control sequence (often for things like applying a colouring) then I'll make a procedure to do the job:

```
proc wrapped {string} {
    # These use Unicode escapes
    return "\u0002$string\u0003"
}

puts [wrapped "this is some test text"]
```